# Simple Date Format Parsing -getting incorrect result

Tags: java, date

```
Date dateShipped = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS" ).parse("2013-08-29 22:41:03.537");
SimpleDateFormat fmt =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(fmt.format(dateShipped));
```

this results
29 May 2016

Why is the result different?

Comment: I see that you're using both capital M for month and for minutes. That can't be correct, right? I'm not a Java guy, but it strikes me :)

Comment: `MM` stands for Month, it should be `mm` for minutes.

Answer (score 7):

[Date Pattern Letters](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.SSS" )
```

instead of

```
new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS" )
```

`MM` for Month and `mm` for Minutes

Comment: Third time this week for this type of question :D

Comment: ya i know but they didnt check themself.

Comment: Chance to bump your rep any way ;)

Answer (score 1):

try changing your code as following

```
Date dateShipped = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.SSS").parse("2013-08-29 22:41:03.537");
```

Comment: It's probably just me, but I fail to see what benefit this answer brings over newuser's

Answer (score 0):

Change `MM(uppercase)` of minutes to `mm (lowercase)`

```
    Date dateShipped = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.SSS" ).parse("2013-08-29 22:41:03.537");
    SimpleDateFormat fmt =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(fmt.format(dateShipped));
```